# R: Subsetting one column from a dataframe, KEEPING the column name

Tags: r

I'm learning R, and I'm modifying a small piece of code. How do I make a subset of a dataframe, which is a single column, that includes the column name?

This does not work, as it doesn't retain the column name.

```
Data1Subset <- Data1$Level
```

The code sample I'm modifying follows this up with

```
colnames(Data1)
```

Also, `is.data.frame(Data1)` is `TRUE`

Comment: `Data1Subset <- Data1[,'Level',drop=F]`

Answer (score 1):

I finally found this with Google

```
Data1Subset <- subset(Data1, select = "Level")
```

Comment: Nice, Kyle. Great that you sought an answer and found it :)

Comment: I did look first.  Google usually works better for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
Data1Subset <- Data1["Level"]
```